# String encoding for memory optimization

Tags: c++, string, c++11, optimization

I have a stream of strings in format something like this `a:b`, `d:a`, `t:w`, `i:r`, etc. Since I keep on appending these string, in the end it becomes a very large string.

I am trying to encode, for example:

```
a:b -> 1
d:a -> 2
etc.
```

My intension is to keep the final string as small as possible to save on memory. Hence I need to give single digit value to string occuring maximum number of times.

I have following method in mind:

Create: `map<string, int>` - this will keep the string and its count. In the end I will replace string with maximum count with 1, next with 2 and so on till last element of map.

Currently size of final string are ~100,000 characters.

I can't compromise on speed, please suggest if anyone has better technique to achieve this.

Comment: `unordered_map` will likely give better performance. But as usual the only real answer is try different techniques and time them. There's too many variables for anyone to give definitive advice. This is a problem you are going to have to solve.

Comment: A string `"a:b"` has length 4 (if stored as C string). Mapping it to an `int` (probably 4 bytes as well) doesn't bring any optimization. Actually, you still represent a string by 4 bytes plus the additional administrative data for the map.

Comment: Has it to be a readable string mandatorily? Otherwise you could use a array of char or an array of struct.

Comment: If you only have [a-z]:[a-z], the nr of possible strings is 26^2=676 different elements. So you could just order the character pairs lexicographically and put them in a vector<int> with 676 elements. E.g. vec[0] counts nr of "a:a", and vec[675] counts nr of "z:z".

Comment: @Scheff  I will use ASCII character '1'. Not an integer, in the end i need to keep it as a compact string only.

Comment: @P.PICARD i just need a compressed string, i don't need to get any info from it, i may just use it to compare with other compacted string, thats all.

Comment: @ErikAlapää oh no, alphabets are just examples, my string will consists any of the ASCII character.

Comment: @instance Then it is 256^2, an array of 65000 ints, also quite manageable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your input strings are of the range "a:a"..."z:z" and you simply need to count the appearances of each in the stream, regardless of order. If your distribution is even enough you can count them in using a uint16_t.
A map is implemented using a tree, so an array is much more efficient than a map both in memory and time.
So you can define an array

```
array<array<uint16_t, 26>, 26> counters = {{}};
```

and assuming your input is, for example `input = "c:d"`, you can fill up the array as follows

```
    counters[input[0]-'a'][input[2]-'a']++;
```

Then finally you can print out the frequencies of the input like this

```
for (auto i=0; i < counters.size() ; ++i) {
  for (auto j=0; j < counters[i].size(); ++j) {
    cout<<char(i+'a')<<":"<<char(j+'a')<<" "<<counters[i][j]<<endl;
  }
}
```